# How to call a particular function in a C program periodically via cronjob scheduling?

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio, ubuntu, job-scheduling

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <var.h>
    
    void checksumrefresh(void)
    {
        a + b = s;
        printf("%d\n",s);
    }
```

I know to call a program periodically on a cronjob scheduling by

> 20 * * * */home/users/Desktop/prog.out

but here in the above program how can I call checksumrefresh() function every 30 minutes by a cornjob scheduling.

P.S: The main() is on the other file.
Anyone please help me on this as I am new to cornjob scheduling

Comment: call sum in the main program. main is called when you start program.

Comment: @MajidHajibaba: But my requirement is to call the function from a cronjob scheduling

Comment: You cannot call a function inside C without using main.

Comment: Crond doesn't know anything about functions. It only invokes programs.
Either make this function a standalone program, or add to the existing main() a command line option to just execute this function and exit.
P.S. I know it is just an example, but you better put meaningful code (or at least one that compiles)...

Comment: You could use CRON to run a program (e.g. `kill`) that sends a signal (e.g. `USR1`) to your program, then call the function from within a signal handler.

Answer (score 0):

crond does not know where to start in your program, since it is not really a program (read executable). To make it an executable you should either call your function inside a function with (at least) the prototype `int main();`, or you should put your code inside that main function.

### Option 1

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <var.h>
    
void checksumrefresh(void)
{
    a + b = s;
    printf("%d\n",s);
}

int main()
{
    checksumrefresh();
}
```

### Option 2

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <var.h>
    
int main()
{
    a + b = s;
    printf("%d\n",s);
}
```